# One of machines on esxi vsphere stops working without any errors

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere

I have some virtual machines on one of my servers. One of them has stopped working a few days ago with a cpu error on esxi, so I upgraded the machine's cpu from 4 cores to 10 cores. And it has 20 GB RAM for memory and also has enough disk space.

This machine is just for an application for entry and exit checking for employees and its connected to an entry and exit clock device. After that happened, I had to reboot the machine and it was working correctly without errors, but after a few hours, the machine just freezes and stops and I have no errors on esxi vsphere and event when I want to open the machine from esxi web remote it just shows me a black screen that i can't do anything, and i also don't have the machine's ping and gives me Time out.

So every time I have to reboot the machine. It has windows server 2012r2 and after reboot i don't have any specific errors for this issue on my windows server

I will appreciate you guys if you help me with this

I upgraded Machine CPU's to 10 Cores and Memory to 20GB
I reinstalled Machine's Network Adapter from Esxi Vsphere
but it didn't effect

Thank you

Comment: Questions should demonstrate reasonable information technology management practices. Questions that relate to unsupported hardware or software platforms or unmaintained environments may not be suitable for Server Fault. Windows 2012 is out of life so consider upgrade the OS.

Comment: Increasing the number of vCPUs does not resolve CPU errors. Check the actual hardware for errors.

Comment: Ask the person for whom you work for help with locating the logs. The system also has an operating system that is off topic for this forum.

Answer (score 1):

Neither increasing the number of vCPUs/cores used in the VM nor allocating excessive amounts of memory helps with that error. You might have a hardware problem with the host CPU(s).

Many years back I had a problem with a host CPU that I could narrow down by forcing core affinity in the VM settings in vSphere. I could find that a specific core caused an application to crash in seconds when it was assigned. Avoiding that core, there was no crash in weeks. Rebooting the host removed the problem for minutes/hours/weeks at a time but it always came back. The most sensitive software I found was, astonishingly, Folding@Home which I used for burn in and load testing.

Insisting on an hardware error I could get Dell to swap the CPU (problem returned slightly different month later) and even CPU and system board together (problem went away forever). The real cause was never determined but I suspected a level 2 cache issue.

Your simple application is probably happy with running on a single core which makes troubleshooting easier. I'd work with a cloned, isolated VM that doesn't mind getting trashed.

Mind you, I had some weird data issues at the same time in other VMs on the same host that were hard to detect and diagnose. I'd seriously get that issue fixed.